# Maven test coverage for scala

Tags: scala, maven

I want to do test coverage on my Scala project, for which I use Maven as a build tool.

So I found this:
https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin

And I looked here:
http://scoverage.github.io/scoverage-maven-plugin/1.3.0/check-mojo.html

So now to check test coverage, I run this:

```
mvn test
```

And then:

```
mvn scoverage:check
```

However, this only makes the tests to be run. I get no information about coverage.

Also, I tried:

```
mvn scoverage:report
```

But the result is the same.

So how can I use this tool or another to get test coverage info in a Scala/Maven project?

Answer (score 1):

I have only used Scoverage with SBT, but chances are the usage is the same.

`mvn scoverage:check` will only generate some metadata - XML - and compare the generated coverage values against any coverage minimum you might have set up.

With `mvn scoverage:report` you will get some formatted reports. More docs [here](http://scoverage.github.io/scoverage-maven-plugin/1.3.0/report-mojo.html).

Comment: I tried that as well unsuccessfully. Where does it place those reports? Does it create a file somewhere?(I can't find any)

Comment: Usually under target/scoverage-report or something similar.. Do you have submodules? You might need to set the 'aggregate' flag to true if so

Comment: Run `mvn scoverage:check` to check coverage level or `mvn scoverage:report` to generate report.
Check logs for information if and why coverage was skipped (if it was).
Report will be generated in `target/site/scoverage` directory.